# Is values-sw300dp working on lower versions of Android?

Tags: android

I see that `values-small` is deprecated and `values-sw300dp` is the new way to go starting in 3.2.

But does it mean `values-sw300dp` works on versions < 3.2 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just scroll down to `SmallestWidth` here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

It says:

> Added in API level 13.

So, no, it won't work before Honeycomb.